# Execute another draw loop for 5 seconds within the main animation loop?

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have a "simple" game with an animate() loop that uses requestAnimationFrame():

```
function animate(currentTime) {
  if(playGame) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  }

  if(isCollide) {
    endTime = currentTime + 5000;
    drawCollision(currentTime);
  }

}
```

I would like to run the drawCollision() code for 5 seconds, so I did something like this:

```
function drawCollision(currentTime) {

  if(playCollide) {
    requestAnimationFrame( drawCollision );
  }

  if(currentTime < endTime) {
    drawImage(image, x, y, height, width, rotation);
  } else {
    playCollide = false;
  }

}
```

However, the two rAF calls seem to run at the same time? OR at least the code after the call to drawCollision() is executed while drawCollision is being run.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seemed to have got it working, had to call `cancelAnimationFrame(animate)` just before calling my `drawCollision()` code - also moved my 'end of game' code inside the else for the if loop inside drawCollision.

The `cancelAnimationFrame` polyFill is included in rAF found at:
http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/